# How to get all methods/functions that contain a particular string?

Tags: python, function, methods

How to get all methods/functions available that contain a particular string? For ex., use *csv* to get all the method/function details which have the csv text in them.

The above is for the sake of learning, each class supports a lot of methods. I would like to filter and narrow down the list of methods, so that I can explore them. Same is the case with functions also, for the sake of learning.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Is it for you to learn the methods available, or for your program to do something with the list of methods? What do you want to search; do you want to search a module, or an object, or the built-in functions?

Comment: You mean *csv* in the name or parameters or docstring of functions/methods?

Comment: @m170897017 csv as in the function and method name.

Comment: @user2357112 - each of the class has multiple methods. For the sake of learning, I would like to filter and narrow down the list of methods.

Comment: It would be good to know why the Q is being marked for close.

Comment: For what it's worth you can call `dir( pandas)` after importing it and see everything in the `pandas ` namespace. You could use it in a loop to make it easier to read.

Comment: [i for i in dir(DataFrame) if 'csv' in i] pulled all the methods in the DataFrame class.

Answer (score 1):

You can examine the `globals()` dictionary:

```
[x for x,y in globals().items() if 'csv' in x and callable(y)]
```

Comment: It is only showing the functions names which have csv in them. I imported pandas and I am not seeing the *csv* methods from the pandas.

Answer (score 0):

If you only wanna functions, you can do something like this:

```
[x for x,y in globals().iteritems() if 'csv' in x and y.__class__.__name__ == 'function']
```

but if you want also classes I recommend you to use [Rob's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8747/rob%E1%B5%A9) way.